# Insert data to Java DB fails with error because column of type integer cannot accept character data

Tags: java, database, derby

im trying to set Dtat in my embedded Java DB and i dont know where my fault is. I tried so many things types of code to insert the data but nothing works  ? With mysql it works but this is the first embedded db im working with

```
try {
            int rows = jTableA.getRowCount();
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/meinedb", "root", "root123");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            String delete = "DELETE FROM ROOT.ARTIKEL";
            st.execute(delete);

            int b = 0;
            for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {

                Integer artikelnummer = (Integer) jTableA.getValueAt(row, 0);
                String beschreibung = (String) jTableA.getValueAt(row, 1);
                String bestellenbei = (String) jTableA.getValueAt(row, 2);
                Integer menge = (Integer) jTableA.getValueAt(row, 3);
                String bestellenbis = (String) jTableA.getValueAt(row, 4);
                Boolean bestellt = (Boolean) jTableA.getValueAt(row, 5);
                if (bestellt == true) {
                    b = 1;
                }
                if (bestellt == false) {
                    b = 0;
                }
               String sql ="INSERT INTO ROOT.ARTIKEL (ARTIKELNUMMER, BESCHREIBUNG, BESTELLENBEI, "
                        + "ARTIKELMENGE, BESTELLENBIS, BESTELLT)"
                        + " VALUES ('"+artikelnummer+"', '"+beschreibung+"', '"+bestellenbei+"', '"+menge+"',"
                        + " '"+bestellenbis+"', '"+bestellt+"')" ;
               st.execute(sql);


            }

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Artikel erfolgreich gespeichert");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Speichern Fehlgeschlagen");
        }
```

exception :

run:
Mär 29, 2019 1:17:41 PM Auftrags.Datenbank SpeichernA
SCHWERWIEGEND: null
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Spalten vom Typ 'INTEGER' dürfen keine Werte des Typs 'CHAR' enthalten. 
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at Auftrags.Datenbank.SpeichernA(Datenbank.java:135)
    at Auftrags.MainWindow.jBsaveOrderActionPerformed(MainWindow.java:1567)
    at Auftrags.MainWindow.access$4800(MainWindow.java:19)
    at Auftrags.MainWindow$49.actionPerformed(MainWindow.java:857)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Spalten vom Typ 'INTEGER' dürfen keine Werte des Typs 'CHAR' enthalten. 
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeExecuteImmediate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parseEXCSQLIMMreply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readExecuteImmediate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readExecuteImmediate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatement.readExecuteImmediate_(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.readExecuteImmediate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.flowExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.executeX(Unknown Source)
    ... 41 more

Comment: Do you get an error message or is the code running and the data simply doesn't appear in the DB? Please be more precise than simply saying "nothing works".

Comment: show us what you tried and what not worked?

Comment: the error message ! and if I comment out the loop it works

Comment: Yes, Error Message. As in: does your code throw any exception. You are doing catch `(Exception e)` so the question is: Does an Exception get thrown and what exactly is the stacktrace of that Exception.

Comment: the sql of the daatabase by insert records : INSERT INTO ROOT.ARTIKEL (ARTIKELNUMMER, BESCHREIBUNG, BESTELLENBEI, ARTIKELMENGE, BESTELLENBIS, BESTELLT) 
 VALUES (1, 'a', 'b', 2, 'f', true)

Comment: its also loading the record when im starting the programm so there is anything wrong with the sql statement

Comment: So inserting the sql above with `(1, 'a', 'b', 2, 'f', true)` works? Your posted code would produce `('1', 'a', 'b', '2', 'f', 'true')` since you put everything in `'`. Maybe your database has a problem with that. THe error message complaints that you are trying to insert a CHAR into an INTEGER field AFTER ALL.

Comment: ah thank you it works =)